# Xubuntu task switcher in Zesty lost its ability to go backwards with ALT-SHIFT-TAB?

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard-layout

Is it me or has the Xubuntu task switcher in Zesty lost its ability to go backwards with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>? Can I fix this? Or is this is bug in the switcher?

**UPDATE 1**

Somehow, pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> and then <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> is being detected as <kbd>ISO Next Group</kbd>, whatever that is:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x4ba, subw 0x0, time 92504825, (90,96), root:(841,556),
    state 0x2010, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x4ba, subw 0x0, time 92505241, (90,96), root:(841,556),
    state 0x2018, keycode 50 (keysym 0xfe08, ISO_Next_Group), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: And the solution to have ALT+SHIFT+TAB again is?

Comment: @Notinlist: I had to change the keyboard layout switch combo to WinKey+Space to avoid the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem in Ubuntu `17.10`. The usual <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> (switching left to right) works fine but not when trying to switch between windows (right to left) using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> nothing happens.
Then I noticed <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> **does** work.

So my guess is the best way to avoid that annoyance is to go for <kbd>Super</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd> or, even better, change the key binding in your keyboard settings.